# Multiple Spreadsheets with Gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm really new with Python, and I’m working with gspread and Google Sheets.  I have several spreadsheets I would like to pull data from. They all have the same name with an appended numerical value (e.g., SpreadSheet(1), SpreadSheet(2), SpreadSheet(3), etc.)

I would like to parse through each spreadsheet, pull the data, and generate a single data frame with the data. I can do this quite easily with a single spreadsheet, but I’m having trouble doing it with several.

I can create a list of the spreadsheets titles with the code below, but I'm not sure if that's the right direction.

```
titles_list = []
for spreadsheet in client.openall():
    titles_list.append(spreadsheet.title)
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? I cannot understand about `I would like to parse through each spreadsheet, pull the data, and generate a single data frame with the data.`. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion. I'm simply attempting to create a dataframe with the contents of the spreadsheet. All the contents of the spreadsheets would be represented in the dataframe. I want to populate the dataframe with spreadsheet1 first, then append the data frome spreadsheet2, and so on.  I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In that case, I thought that the to understand the table structures for each sheet helps to think of the solution. For example, is there the header row? And, all columns are the same in all sheet? And, how do you want the order of merging the data from each sheet? Unfortunately, from your question and replying, I couldn't understand about them. So I asked about the input and output samples you expect.

Comment: There is no header row in any of the spreadsheets. There are 4 columns in each spreadsheet, and they the same across each spreadsheet.  Each spreadsheet has about 100 rows. I would prefer to load all 100 rows from spreadsheet(1), then add the 100 rows from spreadsheet(2), and so on.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mix of both your starting code and @Tanaike's answer here you have a snippet of code that does what you expect.

```py
# Create an authorized client
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
# Create a list to hold the values
values = []
# Get all spreadsheets
for spreadsheet in client.openall():
    # Get spreadsheet's worksheets
    worksheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
    for ws in worksheets:
        # Append the values of the worksheet to values
        values.extend(ws.get_all_values())
# create df from values
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
print(df)
```

Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to merge the values retrieved from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to convert the retrieved values to the dataframe.
- Each sheet has 4 columns, 100 rows and no header rows.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve all sheets in the Google Spreadsheet using `worksheets()`.
2. Retrieve all values from all sheets using `get_all_values()` and merge the values.
3. Convert the retrieved values to the dataframe.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
values = []
for ws in worksheets:
    values.extend(ws.get_all_values())
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
print(df)
```

#### References:

- [worksheets()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=worksheets()#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.worksheets)
- [get_all_values()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_values()#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_values)